# Override file operations in Python

Tags: python, filesystems

Is there a way to override all file operations in Python? File operations such as 'open', 'os.rename' and 'os.unlink'.

I want to create a temporary, in-memory file system without rewriting a library. Does anyone know of a script or a library that has this feature? I want to run a library on Google App Engine and it is not possible to write to the file system.

Comment: Could you provide more detail? The short answer is: No, there is not.

Comment: You mean "operation", not "operator".

Comment: You don't explain what you want, which means nobody can help you really as shown by the wild guesses. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need file objects which do not have real files behind them, have a look at the [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) module.

Comment: Yes, and there is also the tempfile.TemporaryFile class which works in GAE.

Answer (score 1):

"Override"? That word doesn't really make any sense in that context. You can replace them in various ways, depending on what you want really.

Making a in memory file system can be done on most OS's through the operating system, like with tmpfs in most Unices. That's probably a better solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the code of your own file system from scratch, one way or another you will end up rewriting a library.

I have no knowledge of any library implementing an in-memory temporary file system in pure Python. As an alternative, in Linux you can use the `tmpfs` file system, usually mounted on `/dev/shm`. You can open, read and write files there as usual.

Comment: Why do you want an in memory file system?

Answer (score 0):

I found this which may be close enough to do the job code.google.com/p/pyfilesystem